# все строки двумерного массива строго упорядочены по убыванию

Tags: java, c#, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть двумерный массив.
Надо проверить что бы каждая его строчка была отсортирована по убыванию.
Если все строчки отсортированы то true 
иначе false 
Пример 10 5 5 считается не отсортированной строчкой.
желательно пример на java

Comment: Какая часть задания вызывает сложности? Вы можете проверить строку на убывание самостоятельно?

Answer (score 3):

передаешь в функцию массив,
циклом проходишь по строкам,
вторым циклом проходишь по элементам строки, если элемент больше предыдущего, выходишь из функции и возвращаешь значение false
после циклов возвращаешь значение true

Comment: надеюсь, вы друг друга поняли) пс: хотя по факту вы правы, но ваш русский "из вэри бэд"

Answer (score 0):

Вот одна из возможных реализаций на **C++** с проходом по массиву в цикле и установлением флага `true` в случае строгой упорядоченности по убыванию и `false` в противном случае:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

const unsigned columns = 3, rows = 3;

int arr[columns][rows] = {
    { 3, 2, 1 },
    { 7, 6, 5 },
    { 10, 5, 5 }
};

bool sort = false;
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] < arr[i][j-1]) {
            sort = true;
        }
        else {
            sort = false;
            goto endsort;
        }
    }
}
endsort:
std::cout << sort << std::endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Проверка кода: [ideone](https://ideone.com/cHe373)

Comment: Результат true (1) возможен только при полном проходе по массиву, результат false (0) может возникнуть аварийно при первом же несоответствии условии строгой упорядоченности по убыванию.